# How to serve a txt file in an Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I have to follow these steps to verify my app, but I am having trouble making a route to link to my file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/syNzC.jpg

The link above is the instructions I was given, I created the text file and I have it in my assets folder in my angular 2 app. However I have no idea how to create the route http://www.example.com/riot.txt so that it refers to my txt document file. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm using Angular 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a route in Angular at all. If you're using the Angular CLI (or a similar setup) you can put the file in your `src` directory and add it to the `assets` property in the `.angular-cli.json` file.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new blog
echo 'Hello, World' > src/greeting.txt
```

Your .angular-cli.json would look like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "blog"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "greeting.txt",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Then you can run ng serve.

```
ng serve
```

As you can see, this is an issue in configuring your web server to serve static files - which most should by default.

Comment: why is ths not working with mydomain.com/greeting.txt ?

Comment: after you made the change you need to stop current local development and restart ng serve command

Answer (score -1):

you probably already found a way to do this, but here is how I was able to verify my app with riot:

On my `Nginx` config file, I added the /location with the path to the file

```
server {
    listen 80;

    // this is what you use to handle your routes
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    // this is how I was able to verify my app
    location /riot.txt {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /assets/riot.txt;
    }
}
```

I'm deploying this app on GKE using a docker image built with this Dockerfile:

```
#############
### build ###
#############

# base image
FROM node:15.3.0-alpine3.10 as build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY ./web/package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

# add app
COPY ./web /app

# generate build
RUN ng build --output-path=dist

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# replace nginx default.conf with my conf (default.conf) 
COPY --from=build /app/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Hope you find this useful.